# Change Capture Alternatives for ETL

Tags: sql-server, etl, cdc

We need to extract data from a SQL database to the data lake, transform using azure data flow, and load data into an Azure SQL database as the final destination.

The SQL database tables have only the insert DateTime of the records. Update DateTime of the records are not captured. New records can be brought incrementally based on the insert date value but we are trying to find a way to capture updated records and bring those records incrementally **without doing any modifications to the source database**. Therefore we are not in a state to enable CDC or create triggers.

We had come through the below resource explaining the hash comparisons.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6110/change-capture-alternatives-with-azure-data-factory/

But in those approaches, we have to follow the below steps

1. Bring the full data set of all tables to the lake
2. Do the transformations to the whole data set
3. Load the data set into the staging layer in the ASQL database
4. Generate Hash and compare that hash values with the hash values of the existing data set in the ASQl database.

Since we have to bring and transform the **full data set every day** we see this approach as a costly one since it's not supporting incremental extraction.

Is there any better way of handling this kind of a scenario?

(Tech Stack : MS SQL , ADF, Azure data lake, Azure SQL)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You've got to pay the cost somewhere. By saying that you can't change the source system in any way and saying that an ELT process (as you've described it) is expensive, you're implying that you're not willing to pay the cost anywhere.

Comment: Apologies. what I wanted to highlight was hashing solution is not supporting for incremental load as we have to bring all data every time.  I have edited the question.